# Getting current date, time, and day in Laravel

Tags: php, date

I need to get the current date, time, and day using Laravel.

I tried to echo  `$ldate = new DateTime('today');` and `$ldate = new DateTime('now');`

But it is always returning 1.

How can I get the current date, time, and day?

Comment: I think the main problem is that you're doing `echo $now = new DateTime();` whereas instead you should just set the variable without the `echo` (i.e. do `$now = new DateTime();`) and then when you want to echo it you need to use the `format()` method ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)): `echo $now->format('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 321, accepted):

Laravel has the `Carbon` dependency attached to it.

`Carbon::now()`, include the `Carbon\Carbon` namespace if necessary.

Edit (usage and docs)

Say I want to retrieve the date and time and output it as a string.

```
$mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
echo $mytime->toDateTimeString();
```

This will output in the usual format of `Y-m-d H:i:s`, there are many pre-created formats and you will unlikely need to mess with PHP date time strings again with Carbon.

Documentation:
https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

String formats for Carbon:
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

Comment: use Carbon\Carbon; is the namespace declaration

Comment: how to extract dayname from 2016/2/20 in laravel 5??
please reply

Comment: @AngularAngularAngular Use `Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y')`

Comment: catch up on your Carbon documentation. No one will write code for you. The answer provides what was asked by the OP.

Answer (score 102):

Try this,

```
$ldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: This is the kind of php way, how can i go for laravel way

Comment: @Chennai Why do you need it to do the "laravel" way? Laravel is the "php way" :)

Comment: When you have access to classes like Carbon that are fully tested it's always useful to utilise them. Why reinvent the wheel when there's already a robust implementation that does what you need and more?

Comment: @Everon Using built in core functions is not reinventing the wheel. People always want to overcomplicate things :S

Comment: Lets say down the road after you've finished your project you find that you need to implement timezones in your dates to allow different users to have the correct times. Would you want to go back and recode every time you have a date/time field pop up? I doubt it. `date` returns a string, there are core functions too allow parsing of the string but why limit yourself in that way in terms of flexibility? Check out the Carbon docs.

Comment: You just set the right timezone in global config and that's it, the same way as carbon works. It's just silly to do things "laravel way", because it looks more fancy? How is this `\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d.m.Y');` better than `date('d.m.Y')` ?

Comment: Thanks So, the `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` won't hurt by anyway right ?

Comment: @MārtiņšBriedis The Laravel / Carbon way does have its benefits. For example if you want to use their useful wrapper functions to manipulate date objects you can easily do this with very readable code and it also handles timezone issues and other tedious date formatting. If its part of the framework then its always good to use the abstractions.

Answer (score 71):

Php has a date function which works very well.  With laravel and blade you can use this without ugly `<?php` echo tags. For example, I use the following in a `.blade.php` file...

```
Copyright © {{ date('Y') }}
```

... and Laravel/blade translates that to the current year.  If you want date time and day, you'll use something like this:

```
{{ date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}
```

Answer (score 25):

If you want to use `datetime` class do:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) for reference.

Answer (score 19):

From Laravel 5.5 you can use now() function to get the current date and time.

In blade file, you can write like this to print date.

```
{{  now()->toDateTimeString('Y-m-d') }}
```

[image]

For more information check [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-now)

Answer (score 10):

Here is another way to do this

```
Use \Carbon\Carbon;
```

> $date = Carbon::now();
>
> echo $date->toRfc850String();

Output will be like this

```
Saturday, 11-May-19 06:28:04 UTC
```

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
    $date = Carbon::now();
    return $date->toArray();
```

will give you

```
{
  "year": 2019,
  "month": 1,
  "day": 27,
  "dayOfWeek": 0,
  "dayOfYear": 26,
  "hour": 10,
  "minute": 28,
  "second": 55,
  "englishDayOfWeek": "Sunday",
  "micro": 967721,
  "timestamp": 1548570535,
  "formatted": "2019-01-27 10:28:55",
  "timezone": {
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "Asia/Dubai"
  }
}
```

The same props are accessible through

```
    return [
             'date' => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
              'year' => $date->year,
              'month' => $date->month,
              'day' => $date->day,
              'hour' => $date->hour,
              'isSaturday' => $date->isSaturday(),
          ];
```

Answer (score 5):

**FOR LARAVEL 5.x**

I think you were looking for this

```
$errorLog->timestamps = false;
$errorLog->created_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$date = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use a built-in PHP function. if you want to get timestamp format such as "2021-03-31" you can write code like this

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', time());
```

for the time you can write like this

```
$date = date('H:i:s', time());
```

for the day you can write like this

```
$date = date('l', time()); // lowercase of L
```

function `time()` will give you the current UNIX time and you convert it to whatever format you need.

So, you don't need any third-party package anymore :)

You can read more about UNIX time in this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and convert it in this [webiste](https://www.unixtimestamp.com)

Last, for the formatting, you can visit the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp) page.

Answer (score 4):

I use `now()` on laravel 8 to create a user

```
User::create([
   'name'=>'admin',
   'email'=>'admin@email.test',
   'email_verified_at'=>now(),
   'password'=>bcrypt('123456'),
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

data

```
return now()->toDateString();
```

Time

```
return now()->toTimeString();
```

Comment: `now()->getTimestamp()` also working

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of helpers.

The helper now()
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-now

The helper now() has an optional argument, the timezone. So you can use now:

```
now();
```

or

```
now("Europe/Rome");
```

In the same way you could use the helper today() https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-today. This is the "same thing" of now() but with no hours, minutes, seconds.

At the end, under the hood they use Carbon as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$tmp = (new DateTime)->format('d-m-Y');
echo $tmp;
```

to Timestamp.

```
$kTsp = (new DateTime)->getTimestamp();
echo $kTsp;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use DateTime;

$now = new DateTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple:

```
Carbon::now()->toDateString()
```

This will give you a perfectly formatted date string such as 2020-10-29.

In Laravel 5.5 and above you can use `now()` as a global helper instead of `Carbon::now()`, like this:

```
now()->toDateString()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel Blade View:**

> {{\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y')}}

With timezone:

> {{\Carbon\Carbon::now("Asia/Tokyo")->format('d-m-Y')}}

Format available list:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Timezone available list:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 1):

If you need the date directly in a input value of your view this can help you: (myview **.blade.php**)

```
<input type="date" name="Date" value="{{date('Y-m-d', time())}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//vanilla php
Class Date {
    public static function date_added($time){
         date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');//or choose your location
        return date('l F Y g:i:s ',$time);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timezone on you AppServicesProvider in Provider Folder

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');
}
```

and then `use Import Carbon\Carbon` 
and simply `use Carbon::now()` //To get the current time, if you need to format it check out their documentation for more options based on your preferences [enter link description here](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `today()` [function](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-today).

```
$today = today('Europe/London');
$dayOfYear = $today->dayOfYear;
$dayOfWeek = $today->dayOfWeek;
```

Answer (score -1):

today data and time

```
return now::();
```

time

```
return now()->toTimeString();
```

Comment: Hi ali, with 21 other answers already present, it would be great if you could add an explanation to your code to help us understand how it is different from other answers and how it solves the problem in the way that other answers dont. Thanks!