# How to check if the date is greater than today's date Laravel5

Tags: mysql, date, laravel-5

I have a table where there is a column which has event date

but the column is of type varchar.

The date is saved in form of dd-mm-yy

now I want to get all the events whose date is greater than today's date.

My code which doesnot work looks like this

```
$cat=Event::where('date','>=',date('d-m-Y'))->get();
```

But its not working it is getting me all the events

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Use a proper date type, not varchar.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109179/getting-current-date-time-day-in-laravel)  should help you i think.

Comment: @CBroe I know bro I am updating some one else's designed website ,

Answer (score 1):

If your columntype is date, you could use Carbon:

```
use \DateTimeZone;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\BlogVideo;

$today = Carbon::now(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
Event::where('date','>=',$today)->get();
```

Comment: just checked with this values it not working :) ('01-01-2015' > '01-02-2014') it return false;

Comment: I'm using in production environment and it works. I don't know what to say :)

Comment: are you sure you date is varchar? there is no doubt no matter what programing languages that '01-01-2015' is not bigger than  '01-02-2014',

Comment: Ops, you are right, I forget about varchar column type :) Fix the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If column is `varchar` type there is nothing you can do, except change the column datatype to `date` or `datetime`. Then, just do what you did before:

```
Event::where('date','>=', new \DateTime('now'))->get();
```