# Insert the current date time using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-carbon

I want to store the current date time in MySQL using the following Laravel function. Actually, I stored a static date. Instead of this, how can I store the current date time in the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields in the database?

```
function insert(Request $req)
{
    $name = $req->input('name');
    $address = $req->input('address');
    $data = array("name" => $name, "address" => $address, "created_at" => '2017-04-27 10:29:59', "updated_at" => '2017-04-27 10:29:59');
    DB::table('student')->insert($data);
    echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Solution is already available @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109179/getting-current-date-time-day-in-laravel

Comment: yes i checked but error occur at Carbon\Carbon namespace so that i asked question ..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the Laravel helper function

```
now()
```

Otherwise, use the `carbon` class:

```
Carbon\Carbon::now()
```

It is used like this:

```
$data = array("name" => $name,"address" => $address,"created_at"=> Carbon::now(),"updated_at"=> now());
DB::table('student')->insert($data);
```

For more information, see *[now()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-now)*

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this to get the current date time. It's working.

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

And also I have updated and set things in your function. You have to add this:

```
function insert(Request $req)
{
    $name = $req->input('name');
    $address = $req->input('address');

    $current_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $data = array("name" => $name,
                  "address" => $address,
                  "created_at" => $current_date_time,
                  "updated_at" => $current_date_time);
    DB::table('student')->insert($data);
    echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
    return redirect('/');
 }
```

Comment: Notice that this solution will use the PHP server date-time, not necessarily the same date-time as the database server you would get using now() in MySQL or getDate() in SQLServer.

Answer (score 3):

Use this in your database query:

```
'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DateTime` object.

Look at the below code:

```
$curTime = new \DateTime();
$created_at = $curTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$updateTime = new \DateTime();
$updated_at = $updateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

at the header of the controller. This code work for Laravel 9:

```
$updated = Carbon::now();
```

You may save it inside a variable and use the variable for inserting and updating statements or for any other purpose.

During *migration*, I defined the column *check_at* as datetime. And I used the following command for table creation.

```
php artisan migrate
```

It generates a timestamp-type column in MySQL. I am passing the variable $updated for update purposes. While using [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin), I can see the column *check_at* has data in date-time format.